# Checking for empty str in IF

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code below :

```
for result in s.find_all(attrs={"ng-bind-html":"entry.result"}):
    if result.text.rstrip().lstrip() == '':
        0 
    else:
        l_result.append(result.text.rstrip().lstrip())
```

This works fine, I need the IF to check for blank result values before loading to a list.

I originally wrote this as :

```
for result in s.find_all(attrs={"ng-bind-html":"entry.result"}):
    if result.text.rstrip().lstrip() <> '':
        l_result.append(result.text.rstrip().lstrip())
```

But I get an syntax error on the IF line.  Any ideas why the first code block works but the simpler second block fails?

Comment: When is `<>` a Python thing??? You're expected to write `!=`...

Comment: `<>` *used* to be valid Python; in Python 2 it was a synonym for `!=`. It was removed from Python 3.

Comment: `foo.rstrip().lstrip()` is the same as `foo.strip()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you simply use the word [`not`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) for negation. `<>` is not a valid python syntax in python 3. (Updated)

Your code:

```
for result in s.find_all(attrs={"ng-bind-html":"entry.result"}):
    if result.text.rstrip().lstrip() <> '': #invalid
        l_result.append(result.text.rstrip().lstrip())
```

`if result.text.rstrip().lstrip() <> '':`

Can be correctly written as

`if not result.text.rstrip().lstrip() == '':`

Or the much nicer:

`if result.text.rstrip().lstrip():`

Which relies on the truthiness of non empty strings. (Empty strings are Falsey, non emptry strings are True)

Note that you can also just use the `strip` keyword instead of applying both `lstrip` and `rstrip`

```
for result in s.find_all(attrs={"ng-bind-html":"entry.result"}):
    if result.text.strip(): #checks if non empty.
        l_result.append(result.text.strip())
```